# SharePoint 2010 site templates and list customizations

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint 2010 I have a list. I modified the default list page (allitemsg.aspx) to show another list, so now in the page I can show a manager and his sub-employees for example.

Now if I save this site as a template and create a new site based on it, this customization does not carry over. The manager list page will only show the managers, and the sub-employees list will be gone.

Is there a way to make a template the preserves this type of customization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution to this direct problem, but if you used related item views they do carry over.